# flatten nested structure in python

Tags: python, nested, structure

How would I flatten this in Python so that every "widget" is an element of a list?

```
{  "widgets" :[{"num": "1", "letter": "a",
              "widgets" :[{"num": "2", "letter": "b",
                           "widgets" :[{"num": "3","letter": "c"},
                                       {"num": "4", "letter": "d"}]
                         }]
            }]
}
```

So it ends up as

```
[{"num":"1", "letter","a"},
 {"num": "2", "letter":"b"},
 {"num": "3", "letter":"c"},
 {"num": "4", "letter":"d"}]
```

Comment: the real question is how did you get it like this in the first place

Comment: the structure was produced by someone else!

Comment: is the indenting done by someone else too?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After you shoot whoever gave you that data, maybe something like this:

```
def flatten_widgets(widget):
    stack = [widget['widgets']]
    while stack:
        for widget in stack.pop():
            yield {k: v for k, v in widget.items() if k != 'widgets'}
            if 'widgets' in widget:
                stack.append(widget['widgets'])

>>> list(flatten_widgets(a))

[{'letter': 'a', 'num': '1'},
 {'letter': 'b', 'num': '2'},
 {'letter': 'c', 'num': '3'},
 {'letter': 'd', 'num': '4'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a recursive [solution](http://repl.it/Tct/1):

```
def flatten_widget(widget):
    assert isinstance(widget, dict)

    # Remove any sub-level widgets for processing
    widgets = widget.pop('widgets', None)

    # The first object is itself, unless it contains nothing
    flat_list = [widget] if widget else []

    # If there are sub-level widgets, flatten them
    if widgets:
        assert isinstance(widgets, list)
        # Recursively flatten each widget and add it return list
        for w in widgets:
            flat_list += flatten_widget(w)

    # Return all widgets in a list
    return flat_list

print flatten_widget(widget)
# [{'num': '1', 'letter': 'a'}, {'num': '2', 'letter': 'b'}, {'num': '3', 'letter': 'c'}, {'num': '4', 'letter': 'd'}]
```

Note that it won't detect cycling references. Also it assumes that you don't mind the original data structure would be modified. I haven't benchmarked it but I would guess not having to copy each dict item would be a bit faster.

Answer (score 0):

This was my hasty response; after penning, I realized it doesn't have the list items in the order you specified; however I think this might point you in the right direction vis-a-vis recursion, just as the other answers here have.

*Note: did not import python module "elegance". ;)*

```
def getflattenedwidgetlist(thislist):
    thislevellist = list()
    for dictionary in thislist:
        thisdict = dict()
        thislevellist.append(thisdict)
        for key in dictionary:
            if key != "widgets":
                thisdict[key] = dictionary[key]

        if "widgets" in dictionary:
            return getflattenedwidgetlist(dictionary["widgets"]) + [thisdict]

    return thislevellist


stuff = {
   "widgets" :[{
       "num": "1",
       "letter": "a",
       "widgets" :[{
         "num": "2",
         "letter": "b",
         "widgets" :[{
             "num": "3",
             "letter": "c"
           },
           { 
            "num": "4",
            "letter": "d"
           }]
        }]
    }] 
}

print getflattenedwidgetlist([stuff])
```